# Question about bash behavior with non-interactive mode

Tags: command-line, bash

I basically need to understand the following behavior:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
$ bash -c echo $SHELL
```

`bash -c echo $SHELL` produces a blank output, and this confuses me because I would expect the SHELL to be set. This is true for $BASH_VERSION as well.

Can someone explain this to me?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `man bash`:

```
   -c        If the -c option is present, then commands are read from  the
             first non-option argument command_string.  If there are argu‐
             ments after the command_string, the  first  argument  is  as‐
             signed  to $0 and any remaining arguments are assigned to the
             positional parameters.
```

In `bash -c echo $SHELL`, the *"first non-option argument"* is `echo`, while `$SHELL` is expanded by your current interactive shell and passed to `bash` as positional parameter `$0`. Since `echo` has no arguments *itself*, `bash -c echo` prints an empty string. Meanwhile, `$0` is set to `/bin/bash` but ignored.

Depending on what you are trying to do, you can either do

```
bash -c 'echo $SHELL'
```

which passes `echo $SHELL` as *command_string* to the non-interactive bash shell (outputing the value of the non-interactive shell's `$SHELL`), or

```
bash -c 'echo $0' $SHELL
```

which passes (the expansion of) the interactive shell's `$SHELL` to the non-interactive bash shell as  `$0`, then echoes its value.